# C# is not trusting installed certificate

Tags: c#, iis, ftp, x509certificate2

I set up a [FTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) server in [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) with an [SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) certificate which I created my self (using [Makecert.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Pvk2Pfx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550672%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). I attributed the [PFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Certificate_filename_extensions) file to my FTP server.

I have a C# script which connects to the FTP server and always gets the following error message:

> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

I installed the certificate in the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" in the local computer and user.

As it does not authenticate, I took a look via C# on the store:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.AuthRoot, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

foreach (X509Certificate2 mCert in store.Certificates)
{
     var friendlyName = mCert.Issuer;
     Console.WriteLine(friendlyName);
}
store.Close();
```

But my certificate is not listed. When I open the [MMC console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Management_Console)  I see my certificate.

Comment: What reason does it give for not trusting?

Comment: Did the answer help you? If so, please accept the answer, if not add info to clarify.

Comment: I'm sorry Sascha but I can't answer you right away. I'm busy on another project which was priorities. I'll clarify as soon as I can. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, C# doesn't trust certificates without a trusted root certificate - like in the case of a self-signed certificate. The `ServicePointManager`allows to add a function where you can handle trusts yourself.

```
// Callback used to validate the certificate in an SSL conversation
private static bool ValidateRemoteCertificate(
    object sender,
    X509Certificate certificate,
    X509Chain chain,
    SslPolicyErrors policyErrors)
{
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IgnoreSslErrors"]))
    {
        // Allow any old dodgy certificate...
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return policyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None;
    }
}

private static string MakeRequest(string uri, string method, WebProxy proxy)
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    webRequest.Method = method;

    // Allows for validation of SSL conversations
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(
    ValidateRemoteCertificate);

    if (proxy != null)
    {
        webRequest.Proxy = proxy;
    }

    HttpWebResponse response = null;
    try
    {
        response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        using (Stream s = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
            {
                return sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (response != null)
            response.Close();
    }
}
```

From blog post *[How to accept an invalid SSL certificate programmatically](http://blog.jameshiggs.com/2008/05/01/c-how-to-accept-an-invalid-ssl-certificate-programmatically/)*.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick workaround, you could accept all certificates with:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (o, c, ch, er) => true;
```